# Android: SensorManager.getOrientation() is working in mobile but not in tablet

Tags: android, orientation

I used SensorManager.getOrientation() is working in mobile but not in tablet.

```
float[] mGravity;
float[] mGeomagnetic;
float RR[] = new float[9];
float I[] = new float[9];
float orientation[] = new float[3];

SensorManager mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
Sensor mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
Sensor mMageneticField = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

mSensorManager.registerListener(this,mAccelerometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
mSensorManager.registerListener(this,mMageneticField,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

// Inside onSensorChanged

```
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
{   
mGravity = event.values.clone();    
}
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
{
    mGeomagnetic = event.values.clone();
}

SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(RR, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
SensorManager.getOrientation(RR, orientation);
azimuth = orientation[0];
pitch = orientation[1];
roll = orientation[2];
System.out.println("Pitch " + pitch);
```

can anyone help me pls